# Parse GCC builtin functions with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I want to know if it is possible to parse GCC builtin functions with clang like 
 `int __builtin_ctz (unsigned int x)`, `int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x)`. The reason I want to do so is that if I try and parse a C++ file including any of the standard libraries, and with correct include folders, the clang parser code cannot parse standard library files that use builtin functions.

Here is how I configure my C++ parsing:

```
/* CPP SUPPORT*/
    clang::CompilerInvocation & invocation = toolset.getInvocation();
    //Adjust for c++
    auto& langOpts = toolset.getLangOpts();
    langOpts.GNUMode = 1;
    langOpts.GNUKeywords = 1;
    langOpts.CXXExceptions = 1;
    langOpts.RTTI = 1;
    langOpts.Bool = 1;  
    langOpts.CPlusPlus11 = 1;
    langOpts.CPlusPlus = 1;
    langOpts.CXXOperatorNames = 1;
    langOpts.WChar = 1;
    langOpts.DeclSpecKeyword = 1;
    clang::PreprocessorOptions &PPOpts = toolset.getPreprocessorOpts();

    /* CPP SUPPORT*/
    invocation.setLangDefaults(langOpts,
        clang::InputKind::CXX,
        llvm::Triple(targetConfig->Triple),
        PPOpts,
        clang::LangStandard::lang_cxx11);
```

The error I receive is:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_clz'
```